# Suggestion to make tag “kolmogorov-smirnov” a synonym of tag “kolmogorov-smirnov-test”

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

[kolmogorov-smirnov](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-smirnov) and [kolmogorov-smirnov-test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-smirnov-test) look like they addressing the same topic.  The latter seems to be a more specific name and the description accompanying it seems a little better.  While we are at it on meta there is `[tag]` and `[tags]`.  Those probably could be merged too.

Comment: A synonym has been created and the tags have been merged.

Comment: Thanks, @whuber, would you mind doing the `[tag]` tag on meta, too? I submitted it as a synonym when I answered this.

Comment: @gung Thanks, done.

Comment: As this suggestion has been implemented long ago, consider accepting gung's answer to make this thread appear "resolved".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

+1, I agree.  Note however, that there are 79 threads categorized under `[kolmogorov-smirnov]`, but only 9 under `[kolmogorov-smirnov-test]`.  In addition, there is a slight preference for tags with shorter names.  These facts suggest that `[kolmogorov-smirnov-test]` should be the synonym and `[kolmogorov-smirnov]` should be the master.

Comment: I didn't know there was a preference for shorter.  I suspect that 'kolmogorov-smirnov' gets more because that tag comes up first.  But note that it is "mann-whitney-u-test".  I'm sure there are counter examples.  One interesting case is spearman and spearman-rho where the former is described as being about the person and the later about the statistic.

Comment: I'm sure there are counter examples. I also think this is a sufficiently weak preference that it could be over-ridden, if there were some reason. In this case, however, I don't see such a reason (but I'm always open to a persuasive argument).

Comment: That spearman one is at least partly my fault; I sought to distinguish spearman from spearman-rho, because Spearman was responsible for more things relevant to CV than just the nonparametric correlation; it seemed to make sense to make the two tags refer to different things. The alternative (which may well be preferable) would be to simply make spearman a synonym of spearman-rho and leave the (small number of) other references untagged.

Comment: @Glen_b, I don't follow you. What does *spearman* have to do with this?

Comment: That was in response to rpierce's comment immediately under your answer, which raises `spearman` vs `spearman-rho`.

Comment: @Glen_b, oh. That seems like a reasonable case, though. It's not like your tag was `charles-edward-spearman`. The man & the statistic are different & could legitimately have 2 tags.